# Org.Apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException: Failed to encode '全国' in character set 'ISO-8859-1'

Tags: sql, hive, encode

```
select
t1.city_name
from
(
        select
        '全国' as city_name
        from
        stg.t_vip

        union all

        select
                cc.city_name
        from
                stg.t_city_config cc
        join
                stg.t_vip v
        on
                v.city_id = cc.city_id
) t1
full join
(
 select
 '全国' as city_name
   from
     stg.t_vip_trade
 ) t2
on
t1.city_name = t2.city_name;

select
t1.city_name
from
(
        select
        '全国' as city_name
        from
        stg.t_vip

        union all

        select
                cc.city_name
        from
                stg.t_city_config cc
) t1
full join
(
 select
 '全国' as city_name
   from
     stg.t_vip_trade
 ) t2
on
t1.city_name = t2.city_name;
```

Why the second SQL is OK while the first one post an error:

```
Failed to encode '全国' in character set 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Answer (score 2):

May add such code :

System.setProperty("saffron.default.charset",ConversionUtil.NATIVE_UTF16_CHARSET_NAME);
    System.setProperty("saffron.default.nationalcharset",ConversionUtil.NATIVE_UTF16_CHARSET_NAME);
    System.setProperty("saffron.default.collation.name",ConversionUtil.NATIVE_UTF16_CHARSET_NAME + "$en_US");

Answer (score -1):

Because `全国` are letters not included in ISO-8859-1. Make sure, you use UTF-8 or UTF-16 instead.

Comment: You can only use UTF-16, because Calcite does not have support for UTF-8 nor it is going to have in the foreseeable future, judging by http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/calcite-dev/201710.mbox/%3CCAPSgeETv5aJ3GKAkoYhCN7oihu9cNLwwLFrs7AsTmC-9WTk2aw@mail.gmail.com%3E