# How can I change calcite's default encode character set?

Tags: apache-calcite

I use driver manager (eg. jdbc:calcite:inline) to get a calcite connection and run sql with it, but calcite's default encode character set(ISO) don't support Chinese characters, I want to find a method to change the encode character set.

I tried the following two sql:

1. select * from tb where id= '啊'
2. select * from tb where id= _UTF16'啊'

Firstly,I run a sql(select * from tb where `id`= '啊') and receive a error 
 that is "org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException: Failed to encode '啊' in character set 'ISO-8859-1'".

Secondly, I add a character set to the sql(select * from tb where `id`= _UTF16'啊'),but I receive another error that is "SqlValidatorException: Cannot apply = to the two different charsets ISO-8859-1 and UTF-16LE".

Comment: I have resolved this problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888393/org-apache-calcite-runtime-calciteexception-failed-to-encode-%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD-in-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the property `calcite.default.charset` to whatever character set you want to use. That said, I'm not sure this will solve all your problems. Support for other character sets is really a work in progress. See [this discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/944838cb40a34d19f5d0a50ed1e86e5fbd181cd8a529c3d98ef40f46@%3Cdev.calcite.apache.org%3E) on the project mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Background:

- calcite version is 1.27.0
- Execute queries over JdbcSchema like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE title IN ('中文', '简体')`

Solution:

Step 1: Override the `org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlDialect` by copying the [source](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/calcite-1.27.0/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/SqlDialect.java) to your project. And then modify the `quoteStringLiteral` method (about line 420):

```
public void quoteStringLiteral(StringBuilder buf, @Nullable String charsetName, String val) {
    
    // remove `if (...) quoteStringLiteralUnicode(...)`

    if (charsetName != null) {
        buf.append("_");
        buf.append(charsetName);
    }
    buf.append(literalQuoteString);
    buf.append(val.replace(literalEndQuoteString, literalEscapedQuote));
    buf.append(literalEndQuoteString);
}
```

Step 2: Create a property file named `saffron.properties` under the project resources directory with the following content:

```
calcite.default.charset = utf8
```